# Setting Variable to Different Custom View Based on Qualifier (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller that switches between views every time it is initialized (i.e. first time it is initialized it should use View1, second time it should use View2, etc).

How can I use one variable and set it to one of those two views depending on which one it should be?

I have tried declaring the view as a UIView and then instantiating it to either View1 or View2, but then the properties inside View1/View2 cannot be accessed because "UIView does not have property named X". I can cast the view to either View1 or View2 everytime I need to access a property, but that seems sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one variable for View1 and another for View2, and then use a boolean or an enum to indicate which view is currently being presented.

If you want only use one variable for both views, then the two views must confirm to the same protocol or you have to use down casting. Something like this: `view as! MyView1` or `view as! MyView2` which bypasses the type checking.

Answer (score 0):

@ukim mentioned protocols, which is the right answer.  Adding this with an example.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController{
     var customView: CustomViewProtocol?

     func updateCustomView( string: String){
         guard let customView = customView else {return}
         customView.doSomething()
         customView.doSomethingElse(with string)
     }
}

protocol CustomViewProtocol {
     func doSomething()
     func doSomethingElse(with this: String)
} 

class CustomViewOne: UIView{
}
extension CustomViewOne: CustomViewProtocol {
     func doSomething(){
          //add custom logic
}
     func doSomethingElse(with this: String)
          //add custom logic
} 

class CustomViewTwo: UIView{
}
extension CustomViewTwo: CustomViewProtocol {
     func doSomething(){
          //add custom logic
}
     func doSomethingElse(with this: String)
          //add custom logic
}
```